# Can't kill cpulimit via psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, kill, psutil

I execute a process via Python's `psutil` which es responsible for heavy load. Thus, I limit its CPU usage via `cpulimit`.

```
import psutil
dd = psutil.Popen(["dd", "if=/dev/urandom", "of=/dev/zero"])
cpulimit = psutil.Popen(["cpulimit", "-q", "-z", "-p", str(dd.pid), "-l", "10"])
```

This code is working so far. However, I can't kill `cpulimit`. After `cpulimit.kill()` I can still see the process with the process ID `cpulimit.pid` in the task manager. The process is exited when `del cpulimit` first.

Moreover, in contrast to `cpulimit` via the terminal, `cpulimit.kill()` as well as `del cpulimit` don't restore the full CPU usage for `dd`.

I know about the killing issue when using `shell=True` in `psutil.Popen` (the shell is killed instead of its child) but I don't do so.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is

```
cpulimit.kill()                          # stop the execution
del cpulimit                             # terminate the process
dd.send_signal(psutil.signal.SIGCONT)    # restore full CPU usage
```

Nevertheless, it keeps unclear why the `psutil`'s kill differs from the terminal's kill.